# Shimano ST-EF51 (3x7) Shifter Compatible With Shimano 200GS (2x7) Groupset?

Tags: shifter, groupsets, grip-shifter

I have an old Montague Paratrooper Bi-Frame with a 2x7 Shimano 200GS and the shifters and brakes need replacing. Will the Shimano ST-EF51 3x7 work with the 200GS groupset?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as the rear derailleur is the same speed, the shifters will most likely work. And for the front shifter, adjust the limit screws so it won't shift to the 3rd gear.

Comment: I never thanked you for your response, you are correct.
Thanks Lam.